# Evaluation of code performances with DO CONCURRENT in Fortran

Tags: concurrency, fortran

I am in the process of exploring some recent Fortran features with the goal to learn as well as understand how they work. I am focusing on the DO CONCURRENT feature in Fortran which is supposed to provide the same speed as OpenACC directives with much simpler instructions.
Currently I am referring to these two resources:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.10151.pdf

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-fortran-do-concurrent-with-gpus-and-the-nvidia-hpc-sdk/

I have build a toy example to help me figuring out this but I am getting some unexpected results. Here is the code:

```
1 PROGRAM main
2    USE myModule_m
3    IMPLICIT NONE
4
5    !> declare some variables
6    INTEGER, PARAMETER          :: N  = 500000000
7    REAL(KIND=wp), DIMENSION(N) :: testArray
8    INTEGER                     :: i
9    REAL(KIND=wp)               :: T1,T2,T3,T4
10
11   ! initial condition
12   testArray = 0.0_wp
13   
14   T1 = wtime()
15   ! test the main loop in serial                                  
16   DO i = 1,N
17       testArray(i) = testArray(i) + 1.0_wp
18   END DO
19   T2 = wtime()
20   
21   WRITE(*,*) 'Serial time is = ',T2-T1
22   
23   ! reset initial condition
24   testArray = 0.0_wp
25   
26   T3 = wtime()
27   !! test the main loop in parallel
28   DO CONCURRENT (i=1:N)
29      testArray(i) = testArray(i) + 2.0_wp
30   END DO
31   T4 = wtime()                                                    
32   
33   WRITE(*,*) 'Multi-threaded time is = ',T4-T3
34   WRITE(*,*) 'Result = ',SUM(testArray)
35   STOP
36   END PROGRAM main
```

With Module file:

```
1 MODULE myModule_m
2    IMPLICIT NONE
3
4    INTEGER, PARAMETER          :: wp = KIND(1.0D0)
5    CONTAINS                                                         
6
7    FUNCTION wtime() RESULT(time)
8       IMPLICIT NONE
9
10       !> local variables
11       INTEGER  :: clock_max, clock_rate, clock_reading
12       REAL(KIND=wp) :: time
13
14       CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(clock_reading, clock_rate, clock_max)
15
16       time = REAL(clock_reading,KIND=wp)/REAL(clock_rate,kind=wp)
17    END FUNCTION wtime
18
19 END MODULE myModule_m
```

I am using WSL linux virtual machine on Windows 10 and I am currently compiling with the latest version of NVIDIA compiler using the following command:

```
nvfortran -stdpar=multicore -Minfo=accel myModule.F90 main.F90
```

The idea is to obviously understand what speed up is achieved by using the DO CONCURRENT versus its serial version counterpart.
If I don't compile with the `-stdpar=multicore` flag, then I get comparable execution times from both loops (the DO CONCURRENT is slightly more expensive but just a tiny bit), which makes sense because there is no parallelization directive at compile time.

If I activate the stdpar flag, I find that the DO CONCURRENT is actually more expensive.
For example here there is some output:

N,       Serial Time,        Multi-threaded time

500        ~0.0                1.712E-3

50000    1.5E-3              4.411E-3

500000   3.95E-4             8.186E-3

50000000 3.396E-2            3.2764E-2

So in order to start to see some benefit, I have to use a huge array size and still the performances are quite comparable. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if this is just the way it is.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wouldn't we expect a load-increment-store to happen about as fast as the memory system allows? Would a "serial" compilation chose to go slower?

Comment: That is, note that `do concurrent` does not mean "do this loop in parallel". It is for the programmer to promise to the compiler that the iterations are independent from each other. A compiler given some code may well be able to make that determination for itself even without a promise from the programmer.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the comment. From what I see in the references I cited (but even others), the DO CONCURRENT statement *is* means exactly "do this loop in parallel" to the compiler. In fact on the NVIDIA website you can see that it is clearly written that it is on the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the loop is parallelizable.

Comment: You can read the Fortran standard to see what DO CONCURRENT means - "do in parallel" isn't, though, one of the things it means. Yes, a consequence of the "indeterminate order of execution" is that the iterations _may_ occur in parallel but there's no obligation on any processor to do this (nor with FORALL). When you use DO CONCURRENT you make promises about your code (yes:  the loop is parallelizable), but this simply "permits code optimizations that might otherwise be difficult or impossible because they would depend on properties of the program not visible to the compiler."

Comment: So, if properties which permit optimizations _are_ visible to the compiler, the compiler doesn't need permission from DO CONCURRENT to do them.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see your point now. But for the purpose of understanding even better, what would be the actions to take in order to run that loop on a number of threads? I mean is that something even possible at this point or one should fully rely on the compiler?

Comment: First thing I'd do is create more computationally intensive iterations (even if all iterations can happen at the same time, that doesn't help if they're mostly just waiting for data to arrive). Second thing would be to create a loop where it's hard for a compiler to parallelize without my promise.

Comment: Also, you should ensure what nvfortran does exactly with `do concurrent`: just multithreading it on the CPU, or sending it to the GPU? I guess it depends on compilation options and on how nvfortran has been installed, but I don't really know nvfortran.

Comment: An additional test could be the explicit multithreading of the classical do loop with OpenMP, in order to have a multithreaded reference. Also, you should apply compiler optimizations (-O3 or whatever) ?